# JBoss training and certification from Red Hat?

Tags: jboss, certificate, redhat

Has anyone taken JBoss Application Administration course or any other courses from Red Hat? How much the emphasis is on Enterprise version over Community edition?

How about JBoss Certified Applications Administrator (JBCAA) test? Easy to pass without course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JBoss Application Administration course and the JBoss Certified Application Administrator (JBCAA) exam both use JBoss Enterprise Application Platform, not the community versions of the application server and related technologies.

The JBCAA exam is a practical exam and most people find it challenging.  Take a look at the [study guide](https://www.redhat.com/certification/jbcaa/study_guide/) and decide for yourself whether you are ready to do all the things it describes in four hours.  Attending the related class is often the most efficient way of learning the material, but class attendance does not guarantee success.  You must master the skills in the study guide and be able to apply them effectively while on the clock.

The exam is currently delivered on EAP 5.0.  If you are only familiar with EAP 4.3, be aware that a lot of things are done differently on 5.0 than 4.3.  Make sure that you spend time with EAP 5.0 before taking the exam.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I and several people in my department at a previous job all signed up for the online version of JBoss Application Administration with RedHat training and had an extremely disappointing experience. The process of paying for the course was byzantine, the online training software didn't work on most of our browsers, and the material was simplistic. I would not recommend it. My experience was in early 2009, hopefully they've updated things since then.